# Gitlab runner unable to pull from integrated gitlab registry

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have multiple images on my gitlab.com registry (registry.gitlab.com).

I am able to pull some of them as part of my gitlabci:

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (782e15da)   
  on org-docker-runner-dev Cz4fZWrV, system ID: s_ab8104dd6bf6 
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 00:02 
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/tf-runner:0.1.1 ...
WARNING: Container based cache volumes creation is disabled. Will not create volume for "/certs/client" 
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry) 
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/tf-runner:0.1.1 ... 
Using docker image sha256:ffd931f7c294dcd42a82579a65c1693ed1ddb2bfc1b6b95fd51bf24c66350d99 for registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/tf-runner:0.1.1 with digest registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/tf-runner@sha256:4b937f08deb883ffd5d4f135ed30b0fbe46719e1e09ba55e01bb9811367730c9 ... 
...
```

image:

```
image: $CI_REGISTRY/org/microservices/tf-runner:0.1.1
```

For others, however, the auth fails.

```
Running with gitlab-runner 16.2.0 (782e15da)   
  on org-docker-runner-dev Cz4fZWrV, system ID: s_ab8104dd6bf6
Preparing the "docker+machine" executor 00:02
Using Docker executor with image registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/kubectl:0.0.2 ...
WARNING: Container based cache volumes creation is disabled. Will not create volume for "/certs/client"
Authenticating with credentials from job payload (GitLab Registry)
Pulling docker image registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/kubectl:0.0.2 ...

WARNING: Failed to pull image with policy "always": Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/kubectl, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (manager.go:237:1s)

ERROR: Job failed: failed to pull image "registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/kubectl:0.0.2" with specified policies [always]: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for registry.gitlab.com/org/microservices/kubectl, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied (manager.go:237:1s)
```

Image:

```
image: $CI_REGISTRY/org/microservices/kubectl:0.0.2
```

I also tried setting up a DOCKER_AUTH_CONFIG var as described in the docs, using a auth: "username:password" string encoded in base64 as gitlab CI/CD variable, to no avail.

The image URL, name and tag must be correct. I can pull the image from my local machine using the exact same username:token credentials.

What else might be missing here?